# Razor pages model validation if either textboxes is required

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Let's say I have 2 textboxes in a user registration form

- Email
- Username

User is required to fill up 1 of them but not both.

How can this be done using ASP.NET Core model validation?

Adding [Required] attribute on both Email and Username properties did not achieve the objective

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MikeBrind I saw this solution (adding AddModelError) in your book too. Does this mean I should not use the [Required] attribute for Email and Username properties?

Comment: Correct. the Required attribute is for a property where you always need a value, not only in some circumstances.